# Composer does not install required dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

My package has a dependency on PHPExcel:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3",
    "phpexcel/phpexcel": "~1.7"
},
```

But when my package gets installed in projects, the package installs fine, but not the phpexcel dependency. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Do you have the dependency listed in the composer.json of your project in the master branch, or just a fork?

Comment: The official package name for most current versions is `phpoffice/phpexcel`. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Danack it's in the composer.json of my project in the master branch.

Comment: I know its a late comment, but I am facing the same issue, did you --by any means resolved this issue ?